# Android Studio: Can't add sdcard to AVD using external file

Tags: development, avd-manager

I've just recently moved to a new laptop (Migrated from Windows 7 to 10) and I'm now setting up my development environment for android. As such, I've created a new AVD using Android Studio. However I can't add an SD card using external file, as the option is greyed out. I'm using the same AVD Setup as in my old environment (except that it's newly created).

I've read that for some people the option remains disabled until they've run the mksdcard tool, I've done this and restarted however I still can't add the SDCard of my old device.

[image]

Also tried creating an AVD with different settings, no changes. Any ideas?
Excuse me if this post is more in-scope for stackoverflow or superuser!